# SharePoint MySites URL Conflict

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, mysite

A user logins into the SharePoint site we have created using their email address and this becomes their username. However this creates a problem for MySites.

When the user creates a MySite the URL it cuts of anything after the @ symbol in the username, so if the users email address is user1@test.com the URL to their MySite becomes:

```
http://host/personal/user1/
```

However this causes a problem if their is another user with the same email prefix but with a different domain i.e. user1@anotherdomain.com. This users MySite URL also needs to be

```
http://host/personal/user1/
```

When the user signs up to the site we create their profile and MySite using this code:

```
if (!profileManager.UserExists(username))
{
  UserProfile profile = profileManager.CreateUserProfile(username);
  profile["PreferredName"].Value = fullname!=null?fullname:username;
  profile["WorkEmail"].Value = email != null ? email : "";
  profile["PersonalSpace"].Value = email;
  profile.Commit();
  #region create User My Site
  using (SPSite site = profile.PersonalSite)
  {
    if (site == null)
    {
      try
      {
        profile.CreatePersonalSite();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {                                           
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("CreateMySite - {0}", ex.Message));
        throw ex;
      }
    }
  }
  #endregion
}
HttpContext.Current = httpCxt;
```

Is there something I can do here to control the URL used?

-- edit

The above behaviour is default for MOSS. I.e. I am not manually taking of the users email address, this is something the MOSS is doing automatically. I would prefer it if I could say the URL should be:

```
http://host/personal/user1-at-test-dot-com
```

I have tried escaping the email address and assigning it to the personal space value like so:

```
string clean = email.Replace("@","-at-");
profile["PersonalSpace"].Value= clean;

....
```

but this hasn't helped.

Comment: Be aware, by the code throw ex; you loose the stack trace! Use just throw;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an uncommon way of doing it, is there any specific reason the users are created based on the email not the username? Anyway, here's a few ideas.

- Use normal naming conflict solutions, include the domain in the url user_domain,
- create an unique Id user_1, user_2 if a conflict happens and check what number is after the underscore to generate the next one.

### edit

Based on your edit, you can configure the conflict resolution in moss itself, that's why I said it was a weird way of creating the urls,

In your SSP, go to MySite Settings, look at the **Site Naming Format** group

Your options:

- User name (do not resolve conflicts) 
  Example: http://portal_site/location/username/
- User name (resolve conflicts by using domain_username) 
  Example: .../username/ or .../domain_username/
- Domain and user name (will not have conflicts) 
  Example: http://portal_site/location/domain_username/

Comment: Due to a solution already implemented we have to use the users email address as they username.